# sip softphone peers source code run

Tags: java, sip

I tried to download and run peers from source from this site - > http://sourceforge.net/p/peers/code/205/tree/

Successfully added the plugins and required jars . Now im stuck here - >

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sourceforge.peers.XmlConfig.setUserPart(XmlConfig.java:307)
    at net.sourceforge.peers.gui.AccountFrame.applyNewConfig(AccountFrame.java:192)
    at net.sourceforge.peers.gui.AccountFrame.access$4(AccountFrame.java:188)
    at net.sourceforge.peers.gui.AccountFrame$5.run(AccountFrame.java:284)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 1):

did you provide a <username> in peers.xml config file? If you're using your own code to run peers, there are several parameters you have to provide using Config setXxx methods (at least username, domain and password).

yohann